# Problem with a javascript toggle switch in xsl

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

This is basically what I want to do:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function toggle(id) 
{
  var e = document.getElementById(id);

  if (e.style.display == '')
    e.style.display = 'none';
  else
    e.style.display = '';
}  
</script>

<xsl:for-each select="s:measCollecFile/s:measData/s:measInfo">

  <a href="#" onclick="toggle(s:measValue/@measObjLdn)"><xsl:value-of select="s:measValue/@measObjLdn"/></a>

<div id="s:measValue/@measObjLdn" style="display:none">
  some text.
</div>

</xsl:for-each>

</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

My problem is that I cannot get the @value to work. If I hardcode a string instead of the @value, it works fine. So the code is esentially working.

EDIT: real path names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function toggle(ele) 
{
  if (ele.style.display == '')
    ele.style.display = 'none';
  else
    ele.style.display = '';
}
```

Use this as current object.

```
 <a href="#" onclick="toggle(this)">
```

Alterntively, use xsl:attribute to set attribute value

```
<a href="#" >
   <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
     toggle('<xsl:value-of select="@value"/>');
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
</a>
```

Comment: I tried the new function with the second option, but it doesn't work IE says "Error: 'style.display' is null or not an object". The first would not work since the format is not quite as I said. I have edited to show the real xpath names.

Comment: ...how then? I cant change how the xml file is structured

Comment: either change ur xsl file as in third block or modify as per first two block. Both should work. adding attribute does not break ur structure

Comment: when I press the resulting toggle I get "Error: object required" also do you think it could be a problem with this: <div id="s:measValue/@measObjLdn" style="display:none">

Comment: How can you set id="s:measValue/@measObjLdn" for a div when it is in for loop. You need to assign the value of s:measValue/@measObjLdn to div. Use xsl attribute again to set different id for div

Comment: It works! i wasnt really sure how to use attributes but thanks